# Change composer UI url

Tags: google-cloud-composer

There is a way to change the autogenerated url?

`https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-tp.appspot.com` for `https://custom-name-tp.appspot.com` or something similar.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, because of the way Cloud Composer 1.0.0 creates the environment, this is not currently possible.

Comment: and what about using the network service like Cloud DNS, can I create an alias?